# Installed Android Studio without SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, installation

I installed Android Studio IDE from here https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html. I noticed that during setup, there's no 'Android SDK' from the installation components.
[image]

So when I ran it, I got this error:
[image]

I'm not sure but I think in this screen:
[image]

Android SDK will be installed. I'm just confused because it says that it is already installed. I can't even check or uncheck it.

I tried re-installing many times but I don't think that SDK is not really being installed. I downloaded sdk-tools from here https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads but it's not being read.

Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: Did you download android studio with *no installer* ?

Comment: Go to your already installed SDK path(C:\Users\hdecapia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk) and rename its directory path(C:\Users\hdecapia\AppData\Local\Android\SdkOld) and then try to install it again.

Comment: Try changing the path of android sdk and then try to re install the sdk setup

Comment: Did you try proceeding with the installation?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the android studio bundle (comes with SDK) from https://developer.android.com/studio/archive.html.